# How to save SQL query result record as integer in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, ms-access

I have a query in Access 2016 and I want to save the record number as integer in VBA module. As example, *Query1* has 10 records should be saved as:

`int query1 = 10`

How can I?

Comment: Could someone have a idea how i can do it?

Thank u very much!!

Comment: Yes, use the sum function of sql

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `DCount()` function :

```vb
Public Sub Count_Records()

    Dim i As Integer

    i = DCount("*", "your_query_name")

    Debug.Print i


End Sub
```

Or use a SQL query with `COUNT()`, and a recordset :

```vb
Public Sub Count_Records_2()

    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM your_query_name")
    i = RST!CNT

    Debug.Print i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`DCount` is likely the most readable method, but just to offer another alternative, you could also use the `RecordCount` property of the recordset, e.g.:

```vb
Sub CountRecords3()
    Dim i As Long
    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Your_Query_Name")
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            .MoveLast
            i = .RecordCount
        End If
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```